# How can you determine a files text encoding in Haskell without using openFile to get a handle?

Tags: haskell, text, encoding, utf-16, utf

The problem is that openFile assumes UTF-8 and the handle returns that as the encoding.
The real problem is I am getting files submitted (by students) encoded in UTF-16LE that I want to identify, so I can convert them to UTF-8. The files don't actually have anything outsde the ASCII range, apart from the BOM markers, which the conversion to UTF-8 sorts out.
I tried the following:

```
fixFileEncoding fname =
  do hdl <- openFile fname ReadMode
     menc <- hGetEncoding hdl
     hClose hdl
     case menc of
       Nothing   ->  system ("cp "++fname++" safe"++fname)
       Just enc  -> 
         do let encstr = show enc
            putStrLn ("@@@@@@" ++ fname ++ " is "++encstr)
            if take 6 encstr == "UTF-16"
            then 
              system ("iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 "++fname++" > safe"++fname)
            else 
              system ("cp "++fname++" safe"++fname)
```

The "@@@@@" line reports UTF-8 regardless of the files actual encoding. I verify this by using the unix `file` command to observe filetypes.

Comment: IIRC the encoding is determined only by your OS locale settings at the time that the handle is opened.

Answer (score 5):

Normally you know the encoding of a file from how it was produced. There are ad hoc solutions like BOMs but they still rely on the producer adhering to such a format.
Without a priori knowledge about the source of a file (as is the case for files submitted by students), the only way is to use heuristics. That's what `file` does. You can also implement a simple solution in Haskell using the libraries *bytestring* and *text*:

1. read a file in binary as a bytestring, using [`Data.ByteString.readFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.12.0.2/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:readFile),
2. try decoding it with some guessed encodings ([`Data.Text.Encoding`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.1/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html) contains the UTF ones),
3. keep the one that succeeds; more heuristics may be needed if more than one encoding is applicable.

To explain the result you observed in your attempt, when you open a file, the encoding is simply guessed from environment variables on your OS (specifically, the locale) That's why you always get the same result with `hGetEncoding`. All `openFile` has to go on is the name of the file, which is not enough context to guess the encoding of a file.